# get last row in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 1 table that have PK is string I can't get last row 
when I use `order by code desc`

**9999** is incorrect

[image]

**73858** is correct

[image]

Help me please T__T

I'm from Thailand sorry if incorrect language

=======================================================================
This problem is solve by [grek40](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5265292/grek40) Thank you so much

var lastrow = db.table.OrderByDescending(x => x.Code.Length).ThenByDescending(x => x.Code).FirstOrDefault().Code;

Comment: I don't see any linq. Show your code as text not pictures.

Comment: "The last row is 9999, but the real last row is 73858", so which one is the intended last row?

Comment: If your Code is meant to be numeric and should be ordered that way, you shouldn't be fetching/storing it as a string.

Comment: When `9999` is the largest/last it means that you compare/order *strings*, not *numbers*

Comment: var lastrow = db.C_ACTIVEL.OrderByDescending(o => o.Code).FirstOrDefault().Code; // Code is string

Comment: var lastRow = YourList.Reverse().First();

Comment: @Novastorm ??? OP doesn´t need last row (which is undeterminstic as every query uses a different execution-plan and thus order of rows is not guaranteed to be similar between different runs), but row with greatest value.

Comment: Ah right, guess the title of the question was incorrect

Comment: Don´t post the anser in your question, in particular when it was described by another user. However mark the mentioned one as answer. Also consider to vote for helpful/not helpful answers.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Sorry this first time for me, Thank you  ^_^

Answer (score 1):

As your `Code`-property is a string values are compared using string-arithmetic where `9999` is greater `73858` as it starts with `9`. What you want is number-arithmetic, so convert your strings to numbers first. Unfortunately you can´t use `int.TryParse` or `Convert.ToInt32` in EF, so you´re stuck on converting your query to an `IEnumerable` first:

```
var query = myQuery.AsEnumerable();
```

Now you can convert every string and get the actual last row

```
var lastRow = query.OrderByDescending(o => Convert.ToInt32(o.Code)).FirstOrDefault().Code
```

This means you´d have to get all the data into memory in order to get the greatest value which might be an issue when you have many rows.

Anyway as others already pointed out you should consider to use a datatype that allows this kind of search-behaviour. Then you could easily avoid these situations from the very beginning.

Comment: You see that your approach is quite problematic, this is why users suggest to use an int-type for your database. Otherwise you *will* have to convert the values on the client-side which is quite inefficient as I allready said.

Comment: IT is SAP database i don't no why SAP generate this as string

Comment: Beacause whoever set it up made it a string. SAP supports int columns.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use proper type in DB, i.e. if Code is actually Int why it is stored as String? As a workaround you can sort by Convert.ToInt32(code).

Comment: IT is SAP database i don't no why SAP generate this as string

Answer (score 0):

If your string is at least well formatted (no whitespaces around), you could try to first get the longest code and then the largest from the longest codes.

```
db.Entries
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Code.Length)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Code)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or in SQL bring the highest code to front with ordering

```
order by LEN(code) desc, code desc
```

Comment: @otaroo If it solves your question, you should mark it as answer. A note regarding your edit: if you only want the code, better do `.Select(x => x.Code).FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.FirstOrDefault().Code`. Your version would crash the program on an empty table.

Comment: Thank you for advice ^_^