# EntityFramework: OrderBy() numeric property when mapped column type is textual

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, linq-to-entities

```
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Entities()
   .Student_Master
   .Where(k => k.Student_Location == Location && k.Student_Course == Program)
   .OrderBy(i => i.Student_Batch)
   .Select(i => i.Student_Batch)
   .Distinct()
   .ToList());
```

Output:

```
 [23,24,28,25,30,26,27,29]
```

require Output

```
 [23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
```

I tried with `OrderBy(i => i.Student_Batch)` but in database  `Student_Batch` datatype is `string` so  not sorting correctly

I tried like following

```
  var data=new Entities().Student_Master.Where(k => k.Student_Location == Location && k.Student_Course == Program).OrderBy(i => i.Student_Batch).Select(i => i.Student_Batch).Distinct().ToList();
 foreach(var obj in data)
   {
     //converted string to int then store in array 
   }
```

Is there any easy way?

Comment: The question is it require to be string when contains integer numbers ?

Comment: but its old database so cannot change in database if i change in database it require me lot change

Comment: OrderBy() lets you parse that weird string to an integer. Just do it AFTER you extracted records from EF database.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes but this will be performance nightmare !

Comment: @mybirthname true but it's easier solution if you have numbers stored as strings. Other solutions are better (query a view where string is converted to number) or add a SQL function for that. Note that Convert.ToInt32() _may_ be understood by EF (honestly I can't remember)

Comment: Is `Entities` an Entity Framework context?

Comment: Have not tried but how about just adding sort to the list? Try  .ToList().Sort()

Comment: yes its Entity Framework  connection

Comment: Have you tried with `.OrderBy(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Student_Batch))`?

Comment: @FSDaniel  when use this  .ToList().Sort()  it showing error

Comment: @haim770 This won´t work on EF, as there is no sql-equivalent for `Convert.ToInt`. Anyway you have to convert to int using `AsEnumerable`. Of course this is performance-wise bad, but there´s no sql-way on converting stzrings to int.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I assume it does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2412950/1625737 although I suspect it indeed may not work for Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: Also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929750/get-last-row-in-linq/40929964#40929964

Comment: @haim77  show this error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Int64)' method

Comment: @haim770 The question is on Entity Framework, whereas your link works on Linq2SQL which is Sql-Server only.

Comment: @m.rogalski  Array.Sort() shows invalid arguments

Comment: @Pravin Try `var mearr = ...ToArray()` and the output of this put into `Array.Sort(mearr)`

Comment: @m.rogalski   finally work your solution  by change in 'toList()' to  'ToArray()' and  and then 'Array.Sort'

Comment: Please change your database structure. This makes me cry inside

Comment: @Pravin in case materialized list is too big and it impacts performance you may take a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5971521/1207195 (essentially you add a custom conversion function understood by EF and correctly translated to T-SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so since the problem is with sorting. You have few options and i will show 2 of them. First is that you can use `Array.Sort()` which is pretty common:

```
string[] values = new Entities()
    .Student_Master
    .Where(k => k.Student_Location == Location && k.Student_Course == Program).Select(i => i.Student_Batch)
    .Distinct().ToArray();
Array.Sort(values); // all you need.
```

Second common way is to create custom comparer and use it inside `OrderBy` :

```
public class MeComparer : IComparer<string> {
    public int Compare(string stringA, string stringB) {
        // your compare logic goes here...
        // eg. return int.Parse(stringA) - int.Parse(stringB)
    }
}

// and use it like 
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Entities()
    .Student_Master
    .Where(k => k.Student_Location == Location && k.Student_Course == Program)
   .Select(i => i.Student_Batch)
   .Distinct()
   .ToList()
   .OrderBy(i => i.Student_Batch, new MeComparer()) // <-- HERE
);
```

Comment: I don't see how this will work. Solution 1 will sort alphabetically, while the OP wanted to sort by the numeric value. Solution 2 will simply not work, because a) `.Distinct()` removes `.OrderBy()`, b) EF doesn't know your comparer.

Comment: @TsahiAsher better now?

Comment: You fixed problem (a) in solution 2, but you still have the other issues I mentioned. If you want to use your comparer, you'll have to do it in memory, meaning after the call to `.ToList()`. This will get all the results, and then you order them in the application.

Answer (score 1):

`.Distinct()` removes any `.OrderBy()` clause, because by definition, `Distinct()` (or `DISTINCT` in SQL) returns an un-ordered set of distinct values. You need to chain your `.OrderBy()` call after the `.Distinct()` call.

Having your values as strings does pose a problem when you want to sort them by their numeric value. If you can't change the database schema, you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24027242/767425) to project the values to integers, and then do `.Distinct()` and `.OrderBy()`.

Finally, you should properly dispose your Entities object after you use it, to close the database connection, preferably by enclosing it in a `using` directive.

Answer (score 0):

As Linq2Entities does not support conversion from string to int (neither using `int.Parse` not `Convert.ToInt32`) you have to convert your `IQueryAble` to `IEnumerable` using `AsEnumerable`. Of course this is performance-wise nightmare, however as SQL has no way on making integer-operations on strings by on-the-fly-conversion this is what you need.

Btw.: Using `ToArray`or `ToList` will also enumerate the collection and put it into the memory.